# How to show this fraction is equal to 1/2?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the fraction:
$$\frac{\left(2 \left(\frac {a}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + a \right) a} {2(1 + \sqrt{2})a^2}$$

Using Mathematica, I've found that this simplifies to $\frac{1}{2}$, but how did it achieve the result? How can I simplify that fraction to $\frac12$?

Comment: Factor out an $a$ on top, multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt 2$. It's really not complicated.

Comment: Just multiply everthing by $a$. Also $\frac 2{\sqrt 2} = \sqrt 2$

Comment: Despite it not being complicated I don't really understand the downvotes. It doesn't necessarily mean the OP didn't try.

Comment: Of course there is the implicit assumption that $a\ne 0$ ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Factor out an $a$ on top, multiply top and bottom by $\sqrt 2$. You're left with
$$\frac{(2+\sqrt2)a^2}{2(2+\sqrt2)a^2}$$
This is clearly equal to $\frac12$.

Answer (score 20):

$$
\frac{(2(\frac {a}{\sqrt{2}})+a)a} {2(1+\sqrt{2})a^2}=
\frac{(\sqrt{2}a+a)a} {2(1+\sqrt{2})a^2}=
\frac{(\sqrt{2}+1)a^2} {2(1+\sqrt{2})a^2}={1\over2}.
$$

Answer (score 8):

I think you may have missed that by definition,

$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}=2$

And thus,

$\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}$

This simplification issue is quite common. Of course using this and multiplying out/ factoring terms may get your desired result:

$$=\frac{(\sqrt{2}+1)a^2}{2(\sqrt{2}+1)a^2}$$

In which the $\frac{(\sqrt{2}+1)a^2}{(\sqrt{2}+1)a^2}$ reduces to one in the case $a \neq 0$ .

Answer (score 7):

Assume $a\neq 0$, we have \begin{align*}
\frac{\left(2\left(\frac {a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+a\right)a} {2(1+\sqrt{2})a^2}&=\frac{\left(\frac{2a}{\sqrt 2}+a\right)}{2(1+\sqrt 2)a}\tag 1\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt2}+1\right)a}{2(1+\sqrt 2)a}\tag2\\
&=\frac{\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt2}+1\right)}{(2+2\sqrt 2)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2}\cdot \frac{\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt2}+1\right)}{(2+2\sqrt 2)}\\
&=\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{2\sqrt 2+2\cdot 2}\\
&=\frac{2+\sqrt 2}{2\sqrt 2+4}\\
&=\frac{(2+\sqrt 2)}{2(2+\sqrt 2)}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ I cancelled the first $a$ and in $(2)$ I factored out the second $a$ to cancel it also.

Comment: Whie I don't see any errors, there are a lot of redundant steps here. For example, you distribute the 2 in the denominator just to factor it back out a few steps later. Also, you don't need to multiply and divide by $\sqrt 2$ since $2/\sqrt 2=\sqrt 2.

Comment: @SE318 I'm well aware of all of that. Since we don't know the particular level of OP's understanding, I decided to write out as much detail as possible. To you it's redundant, but clearly that was not redundant to OP.

Comment: I suppose you are right. Even then though, I would still not distribute the $2$ in the denominator. I think it would be more instructive to rewrite the $2$ in the denominator as a $1/2$ multiplied by the whole thing. Since we want to show it is $1/2$, that seems like a natural strategy because then you just need to figure out why the rest is 1. In my opinion, one way suggests attacking the problem with a strategy, the other way seems to be doing whatever can be legally done which I only advise when you've exhausted other strategies and are hoping to see something you didn't before.

Comment: Or another way to put it, if a student asked you why you distributed the 2, what would your explanation be?

Comment: @SE318 Yup, that's the goal. I never claimed it was the fastest, most efficient or instructive way to do. I just needed to get to the right answer in some manner reasonable manner. And I did not feel like using multiplying by any fractions I felt like OP would have noticed that already. It is clear that OP did since otherwise OP would have noticed and accepted an answer using $2/\sqrt 2 = \sqrt 2$. I got the checkmark initially but then OP gave it to the summary of my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You could try setting $a$ to some arbitrary nonzero value and seeing what happens. I try $a = 3$:

$$\frac{\left(2 \left(\frac {3}{\sqrt{2}}\right) + 3 \right) 3} {2(1 + \sqrt{2})3^2} = \frac{9 + 9 \sqrt{2}}{18 + 18 \sqrt{2}}.$$

Comment: 9+$9\sqrt2$ in the numerator?

Comment: The upvote is curious because this doesn't solve the problem and also contains an obvious error.

Comment: A statement being true for some $a$ does not imply it's true for all $a$.

Comment: @Matt You've never mistaken a 9 for a 6?

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 That's a much more valid point. Still, if the asker tried it, he might learn something.

Comment: @Robert only if it's upside down.

Comment: @Matt Or maybe it was a simple typo. I would have used the number keys above the letters, in which case my typo would have been $8 \sqrt{2}$ or $0 \sqrt{2}$. But what if he used the number pad?

Comment: @MattSamuel Sorry about that, there's only so much Celebrex can do for my arthritis sometimes.

Comment: @RobertSoupe Thank you for fixing my mistake.